# Divisible modules over $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Divisible modules over $\mathbb Z[x]$

How do they look like? 
Is there any characterization similar to that over PIDs?

Comment: Hi there. Have you tried anything? There are easier questions you might ask first; for instance, what are the divisible modules over $R[x]$, when $R$ is a discrete valuation ring? (I don't know the answer to your question, by the way.)

Comment: If one can characterize divisible $R$-modules then one can characterize divisible $R[x]$-modules using their endomorphisms: if $M$ is a divisible $R[x]$-module then in particular it is a divisible $R$-module on which $x$ acts as a(n arbitrary) surjective $R$-module endomorphism.

Comment: Still not convinced, @seaturtles, that it is a characterization. Take $M=\Bbb Q$ and $x\colon M\to M$ the identity. $x-1$ is the $0$ map in this case. I think you need $x$ to be somehow *transcendental* over $Frac(R)$.

Comment: @lolwut: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Brute force approach: Write down a typical divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-module (direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ and $\mathbb{Q}$), determine the endomorphisms $x$, and find a criterion that evey endomorphism in $\mathbb{Z}[x] \setminus \{0\}$ acts surjectively.